# Using WGET command upload files to http

Tags: linux, unix, wget

I'm using wget command upload files to http.

```
wget --no-check-certificate --user=username --password=password --header="Content-type: multipart/form-data boundary=FILEUPLOAD" --post-file filename  http://exmaple@.net
```

This is my error message:

> `FOLDER_NAME'
>   Resolving EXAMPLE.NET... i
>   Connecting to EXAMPLE.NET|10.00.00.009|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Access denied
>   Connecting to EXAMPLE.NET|10.00.00.009|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error

Please help resolve the error.

Note : curl is not install in Server

Comment: Perhaps you are missing some fields in the post query, which the upload form provides?

Comment: Hi Smith, Thanks.. How to pass the upload form. Pls Help me with example .

Comment: any luck...............

Comment: Are there logs on the server?

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR => `FOLDER_NAME' Resolving EXAMPLE.NET... i Connecting to EXAMPLE.NET|10.00.00.009|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... **401 Access denied** Connecting to EXAMPLE.NET|10.00.00.009|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... **500 Internal Server Error**

The first response from the server is an access denied. I would look into the credentials you provided to authenticate. After that see if the error 500 still shows. And test by manually uploading instead of using wget to see that the form works.

Comment: Quick question. What command are you using for uploading and second are you uploading against a multi-part form on your webpage?

Comment: i want upload a file to http using wget command from linux server. CURL command is not install...

Answer (score 1):

After many tries I was not able to upload using `wget`. Kept getting bad requests.

I managed to use `curl` instead:

```
curl -v -F filename=image.jpg -F upload=@image.jpg http://localhost:8080/api/upload
```